# Samsung Multiwindow crash

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-touchwiz

I have an app on the play store which supports Samsung's multiwindow mode,
before the 4.4.2 version of the Samsung ROM, everything was fine, 
however, I noticed that the crash reports started to rise as the OS version is pushed to devices. 
I cannot find anything specific to this on Samsung's dev channel.

The crash is exclusive to 4.4.2.. 
Does anyone have an idea?

crash report follows

```
Version: 201
Android: 4.4.2
Manufacturer: samsung
Model: SM-N9005
Date: Tue Apr 01 19:53:09 CEST 2014

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.android.internal.policy.impl.MultiPhoneWindow$VideoCapabilityReceiver@435847b0
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:671)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1784)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:500)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.MultiPhoneWindow$VideoCapabilityReceiver.unregister(MultiPhoneWindow.java:334)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.MultiPhoneWindow$MultiPhoneDecorView.onDetachedFromWindow(MultiPhoneWindow.java:659)
    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:13429)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2782)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3233)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5966)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:5943)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:365)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:320)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3656)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you register/unregister a receiver in your code?

Comment: "A receiver" yes, this receiver no...

Comment: issue is in samsung device.not in your code i am sure.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410655/android-getting-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-on-unregisterreceiver

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: not to my knowledge.

Comment: thanks for your response. Now I am trying to find a solution for this, because it is happening in some Samsung S7 and S8 devices :S

Comment: do share if you figure something out... very often when researching some issues I fall back on my unanswered questions... :)

Answer (score 0):

Report to Samsung, it seems to be on their side.